# How to use Methods to Make It More OOP

Tags: java, oop, methods

There is a discussion among my friends.
We have a action class which responsible for making password control and other operations. While making this; there are two ways to perform this
 Which one is better and more suitable for OOP :

```
public void dummy()
{
   /**
    * Something else
    */
    if(!isPasswordValid(pass))
    {
        domainObject.setErrorMessage("Password is not valid!");
    }
}

private boolean isPasswordValid(String pass) {
   /**
    * Check Pass and Return 
    */
    return false;
}
```

or

```
public void dummy() {
    /**
     * Something else
     */
    checkAndSetPass(pass);

}

private void checkAndSetPass(String pass) {
    boolean result = false;
    /**
     * Check Pass and Set result
     */
    if (result) {
        domainObject.setErrorMessage("Password is not valid!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the function has "and" word in its name then most likely it violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). And it seems that it's true in your second version. In this context, the first version seems better.

Answer (score 2):

SOLID (Single responsibility, Open-closed, Liskov substitution, Interface segregation and Dependency inversion) is a mnemonic acronym introduced by Michael Feathers for the "first five principles" named by Robert C. Martin in the early 2000s that stands for five basic principles of object-oriented programming and design.
Read
[SOLID_(object-oriented_design)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

In your second approach as [BartoszKP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26842332/2830834) said It is voilating  single responsibility principle. Obviously second approach is not a good object oriented design.

Answer (score 0):

SOLID principle is more about classes but I think way of thinking is also valid for functions, then it is a better that a function should have one responsibility that function name implies so that I prefer first approach because I think the second approach violate single responsibility principle.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple "OOP suitability issues" could arise from your solution. The way you expose your problem and solutions is pretty much **not** oriented to an object oriented solution. You are thinking about actions and operations. In OOP the typical first thinking would be more about identifying/choosing your actors (the objects) and their communication (API or not private method usage).

Having said that, looking at the two alternatives you present, plus what you say about your class responsibility, a more broad programming practice is at stake, the Single Responsibility Principle (as pointed in BartoszKP answer for the method responsibility). Your class should represent something more single and narrow than "**and** **other** operations".